# How can i use the onCreat method if a button isnt in xml (no button id)

Tags: javascript, android, ads, oncreate, findviewbyid

i'm working on a code that use a timer to popup interstitial ads. I want to use the onCreate method to show ads but I'm really stuck, since the buttons aren't in the xml files i cant use findViewById not in a way that i know of im not a pro devloper and im still learning. So is there a way to use the onCreate or maybe to use an alternative?

Pngs assined to each button like this:

```
private void createControls(Context ctx) {
    this.view = this;
    this.context = ctx;
    this.vibrator = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService("vibrator");
    this.dpad = createControl(R.drawable.dpad);
    this.buttons = createControl(R.drawable.buttons);
    this.selectStart = createControl(R.drawable.select_start_buttons);
    this.leftShoulder = createControl(R.drawable.tl_button_top);
    this.rightShoulder = createControl(R.drawable.tr_button_top);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}
```

The whole method:

```js
package com.mliquid.gba.input;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import com.advanceDragon.superSaiyanGoku.R;
import com.advanceDragon.superSaiyanGoku.utils.SmartUtils;
import com.mliquid.gba.wrapper.Wrapper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

public class VirtualKeypad extends View {
    private static final int[] BUTTONS = {2, 1};
    private static final int[] DPAD_4WAY = {32, 64, 16, 128};
    private static final float[] DPAD_DEADZONE_VALUES = {0.1f, 0.14f, 0.1667f, 0.2f, 0.25f};
    private static final int[] EXTRA_BUTTONS = {131072, 65536};
    private Control buttons;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Control> controls = new ArrayList<>();
    private Control dpad;
    private boolean dpad4Way;
    private float dpadDeadZone = DPAD_DEADZONE_VALUES[2];
    private Control extraButtons;
    private GameKeyListener gameKeyListener;
    private boolean inBetweenPress;
    private int keyStates;
    private Control leftShoulder;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private float pointSizeThreshold;
    private Control rightShoulder;
    private float scaleX;
    private float scaleY;
    private Control selectStart;
    private int transparency;
    private Vibrator vibrator;
    private boolean vibratorEnabled;
    private View view;

    private static class Control {
        private Bitmap bitmap;
        private RectF bounds = new RectF();
        private boolean disabled;
        private boolean hidden;
        private int resId;

        Control(int r) {
            this.resId = r;
        }

        public final float getX() {
            return this.bounds.left;
        }

        public final float getY() {
            return this.bounds.top;
        }

        public final int getWidth() {
            return this.bitmap.getWidth();
        }

        public final int getHeight() {
            return this.bitmap.getHeight();
        }

        public final boolean isEnabled() {
            return !this.disabled;
        }

        public final void hide(boolean b) {
            this.hidden = b;
        }

        public final void disable(boolean b) {
            this.disabled = b;
        }

        public final boolean hitTest(float x, float y) {
            return this.bounds.contains(x, y);
        }

        public final void move(float x, float y) {
            this.bounds.set(x, y, ((float) this.bitmap.getWidth()) + x, ((float) this.bitmap.getHeight()) + y);
        }

        public final void load(Resources res, float sx, float sy) {
            this.bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(this.resId)).getBitmap();
            this.bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(this.bitmap, (int) (((float) this.bitmap.getWidth()) * sx), (int) (((float) this.bitmap.getHeight()) * sy), true);
        }

        public final void reload(Resources res, int id) {
            int w = this.bitmap.getWidth();
            int h = this.bitmap.getHeight();
            this.bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(id)).getBitmap();
            this.bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(this.bitmap, w, h, true);
        }

        public final void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
            if (!this.hidden && !this.disabled) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(this.bitmap, this.bounds.left, this.bounds.top, paint);
            }
        }
    }

    private void show() {
        if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
            SmartUtils.showAds(getContext());
        }
    }

    private void showInDPad() {
        if (new Random().nextInt(250) < 1) {
            SmartUtils.showAds(getContext());
        }
    }

    public VirtualKeypad(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        createControls(ctx);
    }

    public VirtualKeypad(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(ctx, attrs);
        createControls(ctx);
    }

    private void createControls(Context ctx) {
        this.view = this;
        this.context = ctx;
        this.vibrator = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService("vibrator");
        this.dpad = createControl(R.drawable.dpad);
        this.buttons = createControl(R.drawable.buttons);
        this.selectStart = createControl(R.drawable.select_start_buttons);
        this.leftShoulder = createControl(R.drawable.tl_button_top);
        this.rightShoulder = createControl(R.drawable.tr_button_top);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }

    public void setGameKeyListener(GameKeyListener l) {
        this.gameKeyListener = l;
    }

    public final int getKeyStates() {
        return this.keyStates;
    }

    public void reset() {
        this.keyStates = 0;
    }

    public final void destroy() {
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.paint.setAlpha(this.transparency);
        Iterator i$ = this.controls.iterator();
        while (i$.hasNext()) {
            ((Control) i$.next()).draw(canvas, this.paint);
        }
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: protected */
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        resize(w, h);
    }

    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
        reset();
        if (isShown()) {
            resize(getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return onTouch(event, false);
    }

    public void resize(int w, int h) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.context);
        this.vibratorEnabled = prefs.getBoolean("enableVibrator", true);
        this.dpad4Way = prefs.getBoolean("dpad4Way", false);
        int value = prefs.getInt("dpadDeadZone", 2);
        if (value < 0) {
            value = 0;
        } else if (value > 4) {
            value = 4;
        }
        this.dpadDeadZone = DPAD_DEADZONE_VALUES[value];
        this.inBetweenPress = prefs.getBoolean("inBetweenPress", true);
        this.pointSizeThreshold = 1.0f;
        if (prefs.getBoolean("pointSizePress", true)) {
            this.pointSizeThreshold = (((float) prefs.getInt("pointSizePressThreshold", 7)) / 10.0f) - 0.01f;
        }
        this.dpad.hide(prefs.getBoolean("hideDpad", false));
        this.buttons.hide(prefs.getBoolean("hideButtons", false));
        this.selectStart.hide(prefs.getBoolean("hideSelectStart", false));
        this.leftShoulder.hide(prefs.getBoolean("hideShoulders", false));
        this.rightShoulder.hide(prefs.getBoolean("hideShoulders", false));
        this.scaleX = ((float) w) / ((float) this.view.getWidth());
        this.scaleY = ((float) h) / ((float) this.view.getHeight());
        float controlScale = getControlScale(prefs);
        float sx = this.scaleX * controlScale;
        float sy = this.scaleY * controlScale;
        Resources res = this.context.getResources();
        Iterator i$ = this.controls.iterator();
        while (i$.hasNext()) {
            ((Control) i$.next()).load(res, sx, sy);
        }
        int margin = prefs.getInt("layoutMargin", 2) * 10;
        reposition(w - ((int) (((float) margin) * this.scaleX)), h - ((int) (((float) margin) * this.scaleY)), prefs);
        this.transparency = prefs.getInt("vkeypadTransparency", 50);
    }

    private static float getControlScale(SharedPreferences prefs) {
        String value = prefs.getString("vkeypadSize", null);
        if ("small".equals(value)) {
            return 1.0f;
        }
        if ("large".equals(value)) {
            return 1.33333f;
        }
        return 1.2f;
    }

    private Control createControl(int resId) {
        Control c = new Control(resId);
        this.controls.add(c);
        return c;
    }

    private void makeBottomBottom(int w, int h) {
        if (this.dpad.getWidth() + this.buttons.getWidth() > w) {
            makeBottomTop(w, h);
            return;
        }
        this.dpad.move(0.0f, (float) (h - this.dpad.getHeight()));
        this.buttons.move((float) (w - this.buttons.getWidth()), (float) (h - this.buttons.getHeight()));
        this.leftShoulder.move(0.0f, 0.0f);
        this.rightShoulder.move((float) (w - this.rightShoulder.getWidth()), 0.0f);
        int x = (((this.dpad.getWidth() + w) - this.buttons.getWidth()) - this.selectStart.getWidth()) / 2;
        if (x > this.dpad.getWidth()) {
            this.selectStart.move((float) x, (float) (h - this.selectStart.getHeight()));
            return;
        }
        this.selectStart.move((float) ((w - this.selectStart.getWidth()) / 2), 0.0f);
    }

    private void makeTopTop(int w, int h) {
        if (this.dpad.getWidth() + this.buttons.getWidth() > w) {
            makeBottomTop(w, h);
            return;
        }
        this.dpad.move(0.0f, 0.0f);
        this.buttons.move((float) (w - this.buttons.getWidth()), (float) 0);
        this.leftShoulder.reload(this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.tl_button_bottom);
        this.rightShoulder.reload(this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.tr_button_bottom);
        this.leftShoulder.move(0.0f, (float) (h - this.leftShoulder.getHeight()));
        this.rightShoulder.move((float) (w - this.rightShoulder.getWidth()), (float) (h - this.rightShoulder.getHeight()));
        this.selectStart.move((float) ((w - this.selectStart.getWidth()) / 2), (float) (h - this.selectStart.getHeight()));
    }

    private void makeTopBottom(int w, int h) {
        this.dpad.move(0.0f, 0.0f);
        this.buttons.move((float) (w - this.buttons.getWidth()), (float) (h - this.buttons.getHeight()));
        this.selectStart.move((float) (((w - this.buttons.getWidth()) - this.selectStart.getWidth()) / 2), (float) (h - this.selectStart.getHeight()));
        this.leftShoulder.reload(this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.tl_button_bottom);
        this.leftShoulder.move(0.0f, (float) (h - this.leftShoulder.getHeight()));
        this.rightShoulder.move((float) (w - this.rightShoulder.getWidth()), 0.0f);
        int x = (((this.leftShoulder.getWidth() + w) - this.buttons.getWidth()) - this.selectStart.getWidth()) / 2;
        if (x > this.leftShoulder.getWidth()) {
            this.selectStart.move((float) x, (float) (h - this.selectStart.getHeight()));
            return;
        }
        this.selectStart.move((float) (((this.dpad.getWidth() + w) - this.selectStart.getWidth()) / 2), (float) this.rightShoulder.getHeight());
    }

    private void makeBottomTop(int w, int h) {
        this.dpad.move(0.0f, (float) (h - this.dpad.getHeight()));
        this.buttons.move((float) (w - this.buttons.getWidth()), 0.0f);
        this.rightShoulder.reload(this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.tr_button_bottom);
        this.leftShoulder.move(0.0f, 0.0f);
        this.rightShoulder.move((float) (w - this.rightShoulder.getWidth()), (float) (h - this.rightShoulder.getHeight()));
        int x = (((this.dpad.getWidth() + w) - this.rightShoulder.getWidth()) - this.selectStart.getWidth()) / 2;
        if (x > this.dpad.getWidth()) {
            this.selectStart.move((float) x, (float) (h - this.selectStart.getHeight()));
            return;
        }
        this.selectStart.move((float) (((this.dpad.getWidth() + w) - this.selectStart.getWidth()) / 2), (float) ((h - this.leftShoulder.getHeight()) - this.selectStart.getHeight()));
    }

    private void reposition(int w, int h, SharedPreferences prefs) {
        String layout = prefs.getString("vkeypadLayout", "bottom_bottom");
        if ("top_bottom".equals(layout)) {
            makeTopBottom(w, h);
        } else if ("bottom_top".equals(layout)) {
            makeBottomTop(w, h);
        } else if ("top_top".equals(layout)) {
            makeTopTop(w, h);
        } else {
            makeBottomBottom(w, h);
        }
    }

    private boolean shouldVibrate(int oldStates, int newStates) {
        return ((oldStates ^ newStates) & newStates) != 0;
    }

    private void setKeyStates(int newStates) {
        if (this.keyStates != newStates) {
            if (this.vibratorEnabled && shouldVibrate(this.keyStates, newStates)) {
                this.vibrator.vibrate(33);
            }
            this.keyStates = newStates;
            this.gameKeyListener.onGameKeyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int get4WayDirection(float x, float y) {
        float x2 = x - 0.5f;
        float y2 = y - 0.5f;
        return Math.abs(x2) >= Math.abs(y2) ? x2 < 0.0f ? 0 : 2 : y2 < 0.0f ? 1 : 3;
    }

    private int getDpadStates(float x, float y) {
        if (this.dpad4Way) {
            return DPAD_4WAY[get4WayDirection(x, y)];
        }
        int states = 0;
        if (x < 0.5f - this.dpadDeadZone) {
            states = 0 | 32;
        } else if (x > this.dpadDeadZone + 0.5f) {
            states = 0 | 16;
        }
        if (y < 0.5f - this.dpadDeadZone) {
            return states | 64;
        }
        if (y > this.dpadDeadZone + 0.5f) {
            return states | 128;
        }
        return states;
    }

    private int getButtonsStates(int[] buttons2, float x, float y, float size) {
        if (size > this.pointSizeThreshold) {
            return buttons2[0] | buttons2[1];
        }
        if (this.inBetweenPress) {
            int states = 0;
            if (x < 0.58f) {
                states = 0 | buttons2[0];
            }
            if (x > 0.42f) {
                return states | buttons2[1];
            }
            return states;
        }
        return x < 0.5f ? buttons2[0] : buttons2[1];
    }

    private int getSelectStartStates(float x, float y) {
        return x < 0.5f ? 4 : 8;
    }

    private float getEventX(MotionEvent event, int index, boolean flip) {
        float x = Wrapper.MotionEvent_getX(event, index);
        if (flip) {
            x = ((float) this.view.getWidth()) - x;
        }
        return this.scaleX * x;
    }

    private float getEventY(MotionEvent event, int index, boolean flip) {
        float y = Wrapper.MotionEvent_getY(event, index);
        if (flip) {
            y = ((float) this.view.getHeight()) - y;
        }
        return this.scaleY * y;
    }

    private Control findControl(float x, float y) {
        Iterator i$ = this.controls.iterator();
        while (i$.hasNext()) {
            Control c = (Control) i$.next();
            if (c.hitTest(x, y)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private int getControlStates(Control c, float x, float y, float size) {
        float x2 = (x - c.getX()) / ((float) c.getWidth());
        float y2 = (y - c.getY()) / ((float) c.getHeight());
        if (c == this.dpad) {
            return getDpadStates(x2, y2);
        }
        if (c == this.buttons) {
            showInDPad();
            return getButtonsStates(BUTTONS, x2, y2, size);
        } else if (c == this.extraButtons) {
            return getButtonsStates(EXTRA_BUTTONS, x2, y2, size);
        } else {
            if (c == this.selectStart) {
                show();
                return getSelectStartStates(x2, y2);
            } else if (c == this.leftShoulder) {
                return 512;
            } else {
                if (c == this.rightShoulder) {
                    return 256;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent event, boolean flip) {
        switch (event.getAction() & 255) {
            case 0:
            case 2:
            case 4:
            case 5:
                int states = 0;
                int n = Wrapper.MotionEvent_getPointerCount(event);
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    float x = getEventX(event, i, flip);
                    float y = getEventY(event, i, flip);
                    Control c = findControl(x, y);
                    if (c != null) {
                        states |= getControlStates(c, x, y, Wrapper.MotionEvent_getSize(event, i));
                    }
                }
                setKeyStates(states);
                return true;
            case 1:
            case 3:
                setKeyStates(0);
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I searched for days without any luck, can any one help me with this just pointing me in the right deriction will be more thatn enough thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a little confusing [from the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#findViewById(int)), but all `findViewById<T>()` does is return an object of type `T` that is a subclass of `View`. Typically you assign this to variable:

```
TextView myTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.my_text_view);
```

This means that anything you can do with `myTextView` in the above snippet (say, assigning a click listener) you can also do with a view object that is created programmatically.

You don't specify which of the elements in your sample above you want to use and what you want to do with it, but since `VirtualKeypad` is the class that extends `View`, let's use that. Somewhere in your code, that class needs to be used. So somewhere in your code you probably call `new VirtualKeypad()` to instantiate the class. When you do, that returns a subclass of `View`, in this case `VirtualKeypad`. So if you do this:

```
VirtualKeypad myKeypad = new VirtualKeypad();
```

That variable (`myKeypad`) is the same as the following (though not yet attached to anything so it won't be displayed):

```
VirtualKeypad myKeypad = findViewById<VirtualKeypad>(R.id.some_id);
```

To go any deeper we will need to see how you use the `VirtualKeypad` class in your app, but this covers the basics of what is happening when you use `findViewById()`.

Comment: from the sample above:
`this.leftShoulder = createControl(R.drawable.tl_button_top);`
is a button that will be pressed frequently by users its a png image in drawble folder named tl_button_top.png.
i want to show interstitial ads when that button is pressed.

Comment: It looks like `createControl` returns a `Control`, which isn't a subclass of `View`. Android wouldn't be able to inflate a `Control` object, so `findViewById()` would never be in a place to find one. As far as Android is concerned, `VirtualKeypad` is a custom view and it renders on screen however it wants, which happens to use these `Control` objects. How you access a `Control` object and handle events for it is between you and the `VirtualKeyboard` object, not Android. This means `VirtualKeyboard` needs to provide a way to attach a listener to that element, Android can't do it for you.

Comment: From Android's perspective, `VirtualKeyboard` is a single unit that draws itself on screen. Android has no concept of the things contained inside that class.

Comment: So is there any other way to show interstitial ads? all im using now is a timer and we all know how much of a bad experience for users that is.

Comment: If you want to get click events from the `VirtualKeypad` (or anything that is part of it) it needs to provide that to you. Is this class one you wrote? If so, you'll need to listen for click events on the view, figure out where in the view they occurred, and then decide, based on that location, what has been clicked and emit any appropriate events to notify other things (such as your activity) that the click has happened. The interstitial ad can be tied to any arbitrary event, including ones `VirtualKeyboard` emits.

Comment: No i didn't write the class but I will make some more research to find a way of getting click events from the `VirtualKeypad` thank you your help was much appreciated